# Receiving jpeg through socket and yet unable to display on Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt, sockets, jpeg

I trying to send and receive jpeg images (image size around: 1kb) from my client socket. I have successfully send and receive the image data by checking the size of the data. However when I tried to past the image data to QByteArray and display on QImage, nothing was shown. The code below is a snippet of the receiving and displaying jpeg image.

**Server.cpp**

```
memcpy(&Rbuffer, ptr, msgCtl.iMsgLen - 8);
ptr += msgCtl.iMsgLen - 8;
cout << "Size of the image data recieve from the send buffer is " << sizeof(Rbuffer) << endl;
QByteArray ba = QByteArray::fromRawData(Rbuffer, sizeof(Rbuffer));
QBuffer qbuff(&ba);
qbuff.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
//QImageReader qimg  ("C:\\test.jpg");
QImageReader qimg (&qbuff,"JPG");
qimg.setDecideFormatFromContent(true);
qimg.setDevice(&qbuff);
QImage img = qimg.read();
if (!img.isNull()){
    cout << "no problem" << endl;
}
imageView->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

Hope someone could guide me on this. Thank you

Comment: What is `RBuffer` supposed to denote?  You do know that `sizeof()` is a compile-time value, and has no idea about sizes determined at runtime?

Comment: The RBuffer was the image data that the receiver should receive. Which I thought by using sizeof() to do a comparison check between the sender and receiver to ensure both sending and receiving have the same data size. Do you mind guide me on how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you have to copy the imageformats directory to your build directory.

eg.
`C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\plugins\imageformats` to `my_build_dir\imageformats`

Comment: Hi even after adding to my build directory, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
QPixmap scaledPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image).scaled(
                             QSize(imageWidth, imageHeight),
                             Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

imageView->setScaledContents(false);
imageView->setPixmap(scaledPixmap);
```